# Elemento não é adicionado com Java script por conta do plugin Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, dinâmico, owl-carousel, owl

Olá, eu tenho um site que pega do banco de dados algumas informações do usuário como o saldo atual, gastos da conta e o total de pedidos feitos no site, então eu usei um script para formatar e adicionar os valores onde eu queria no site

(é um script onde tenho pouco acesso aos arquivos, porém, foi o jeito que eu consegui fazer e que funcionou bem, pelo menos no desktop sendo um iniciante.)

O script que eu estou usando:

```
<script>

// saldo disponível

var numero= '{{user['balance_formatted']}}';
var semrs = numero.replace('R$ ', '');

var perce = parseFloat(semrs)

var rounded = perce.toFixed(2)


var valorfinal = document.createTextNode(rounded)

document.querySelector(".atual").appendChild(valorfinal)

</script>

<script>

// gastos da conta


var numero= '{{user['spent_formatted']}}';
var semrs = numero.replace('R$ ', '');

var perce = parseFloat(semrs)

var rounded = perce.toFixed(2)


var valorfinal = document.createTextNode(rounded) 

document.querySelector(".gasto").appendChild(valorfinal)

</script>
```

Ele funciona como era para funcionar, o problema está no mobile, eu uso o Owl Carousel para fazer um carrossel com essas informações, e ele só adiciona na primeira "imagem" do carrossel, as outras duas ficam em branco.

Já tentei atrasar com o setTimeout mas nada, não sei para onde ir agora, alguém tem alguma ideia?

[No desktop, funcionando OK](https://prnt.sc/ORdmOOB5LVqc)

[No Mobile, o primeiro card funciona](https://prnt.sc/qbaQj0bnzYeA)

[Os outros dois não](https://prnt.sc/PR5jcvKfRWrZ)

Answer (score -2):

Primeiramente, você tem que fazer algumas alterações em seu codigo.

vamos separar cada estrutura em uma função separada

```
function generateBalance(valor){
let semrs = valor.replace('R$ ', '');
semrs = parceFloat(semrs).toFixed(2)
return semrs;
}
if (document.querySelector(suaClasse).insertAdjacentHtml('before', <code> generateBalance(valor)<code/>)) {funcaoQueIniciaSeuSlideAqui()}
```

Da uma testada desse jeito para ver se funciona. caso não funcionar precisarei de mais informações referente ao seu codigo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).